# CollectionViewSource grouping, get sum(Quantity)

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionviewsource

I have a `CollectionViewSource` whose source is an ObservableCollection.

On a `List` or `ObservableCollection`, I can use linq to group my objects, and sum their quantities, but how is it possible to do it on a CollectionViewSource(if it is possible), I see nowhere any documentation about it.

For now I only can manage grouping using :

```
ProductsView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group"));
```

But I see nowhere information on how to display a sum, or maximum/minimum value of a field?

Edit :

Concretely, I want to do equivalent of that :

```
liste_ass = liste_ass.GroupBy(l => l.Name)
     .Select(cl => new Assemblage
     {
         Quantite = cl.Sum(c => c.Quantite),
         ID = 0,
         IdAffaire = cl.First().IdAffaire,
         Name = cl.First().Name,
         Priorite = 0,
         Dessin = cl.First().Dessin,
         Groupe = cl.First().Groupe,
         Priorite = cl.Max(c=>c.Priorite),
         ListeIdOperations = cl.First().ListeIdOperations,
     }).ToList();
```

This is what I would do in linq.
But reading about ICollectionView, it seems this is not possible to do that on ICollectionView, as it is a view, and no operation can be done on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access every `CollectionViewGroup` which contains all the group's imformation including `ItemCount` through `CollectionView.Groups` property. If you want to create a custom group header and show it on UI, here is a sample:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding your view}">
         <ListBox.Resources>
             <local:ToAssemblageConverter x:Key="toAssemblageConverter"/>
         </ListBox.Resources>
         <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    DataContext="{Binding Items, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=toAssemblageConverter}}">
                            <TextBlock Margin="5 0" Text="{Binding Quantite}"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5 0" Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                            ...
                        </StackPanel>     
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>           
    </ListBox>

public class ToAssemblageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var cl = (IEnumerable)value;

        return new Assemblage() {
            Quantite = cl.Sum(c => c.Quantite),
            ID = 0,
            IdAffaire = cl.First().IdAffaire,
            Name = cl.First().Name,
            Priorite = 0,
            Dessin = cl.First().Dessin,
            Groupe = cl.First().Groupe,
            Priorite = cl.Max(c=>c.Priorite),
            ListeIdOperations = cl.First().ListeIdOperations,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want an itemcount, let's say my item has a field "Quantity", I want to get the Sum of quantity in the field quantity. if I have a field "MaxPrice" for example, I want to get the max value of "MaxPrice".

Comment: @Siegfried.V Sorry for the misunderstanding, `CollectionViewGroup` also has `Items` property contains all data items belong to this group, so you can do whatever you want with them

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain good enough, I just edited my post to explain

Comment: Thanks a lot, I look at it tomorrow, even I am a bit afraid as I see there is a converter, and until now I never could use properly converters :(

Comment: Converter takes an important role in data binding. Sooner or later you will need it. And I believe that sooner is better than later. ^^

Comment: yes I understood that, it is not the first time I need them, and until now I always try to avoid them, because everytime I ask, I try to apply them, and don't manage to apply them, but then no more answer so I left it... but I think it is time to begin with hem, I began using MVVM a year ago, now on my software I almost finished main functions, and I am now trying to improve each function. and converters is I think the first thing I may learn... Thanks, tomorrow morning I try it then will come back to you

Comment: trying to understand your converter. First of all why do you have parameters "TargetType","parameter" and "culture"? I don't see where you use them? Or is this so obvious, that I may better try different tutorials in order to understand this? Thanks anyway, for now I can do it without views(I have two separate ObservableCollections), I am just discovering how useful can be CollectionViewSource and trying to change all my solution using them as much as possible.

Comment: Data convertion is part of wpf data binding process. MS define the `IValueConverter` for simple data binding. If an `IValueConverter` was applied to a binding as converter, when data binding engine noticed that source have updated, it call converter's `Convert` method, and provide value of source, type of target, `ConverterParameter`(if your assign it), culture that set to the onwer of the binding target as parameter. In most scenario, we only need to care value and param, and return the value acording of them. Bing engine will use returned value to update binding target.

Comment: I think this msdn article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview will help you have a better understanding of data binding.

Comment: thanks for the link , having a look already. Regarding your answer, I think it's too early for me, first I will make tutorial about converters, in order to already manage easier converters. Then will come back to that one, thanks for your answers.

Comment: Happy to help ^^

Comment: After nine months I found back my question trying to solve something similar again, and that time could all understand thanks. Then I took liberty of editing your code as there was a small mistake in converter. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [DynamicData](https://dynamic-data.org/) you could do:

```
var sourceList = new SourceList<YourType>(); // use this instead of ObservableCollection

sourceList.Connect()
     .AutoRefres(x => x.Quantite) // refresh when this property changes
     .ToCollection()
     .Select(col => 
                col
            .GroupBy(l => l.Name)
            .Select(cl => new Assemblage
            {
                Quantite = cl.Sum(c => c.Quantite),
                ID = 0,
                IdAffaire = cl.First().IdAffaire,
                Name = cl.First().Name,
                Priorite = 0,
                Dessin = cl.First().Dessin,
                Groupe = cl.First().Groupe,
                Priorite = cl.Max(c=>c.Priorite),
                ListeIdOperations = cl.First().ListeIdOperations,
            }).ToList()
            )
       .Subscribe(col => PublicPropertyWithChangeNotification = col);
```

It will automatically update the result when you add or remove items from source list, also when `item.Quantite` changes (if it implement INPC)

Comment: second time you talk me about that in this week, I will go and look at it, I hope there are good documentations on that too :)

Comment: docs kind of suck and you should know something about Rx before. Good jump start are [snippets](https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData.Snippets) and [101 samples](https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData.Samplz)

Comment: oh, and there is [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/) - great UI framework that works naturally with DynamicData, since they are both based on Rx

Comment: Well I think I will take the first option then, I don't know what are Rx, I started C# 2,3 years ago, and began using MVVM a year ago, so I am still a newby...